# Json-RPC in Asp.net Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, .net-core, json-rpc

How to work with JSON-RPC for Back-end process(Web API) in ASP.Net Core C# Without using any third party tools,Is there Any Native Codes
available in Dot-net Core Framework related to Json-Rpc except GRPC